# How to get numbers in sequence in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM alexa WHERE alexapr BETWEEN 01 AND 20 ORDER BY alexapr ASC LIMIT 20";
```

Which give this result:

```
google.com 1
qq.com 10
msn.com 11
yahoo.co.jp 12
taobao.com 14
google.co.in 15
sina.com.cn 16
amazon.com 17
google.de 17
wordpress.com 18
linkedin.com 18
facebook.com 2
youtube.com 3
yahoo.com 4
blogspot.com 5
baidu.com 6
wikipedia.org 7
live.com 8
twitter.com 9
```

It's showing Alexa ranking of top sites, How to get number in sequence like 1,2,3,4,5 etc. Why it's showing 10,11,12 after 1? I want 1,2,3,4,5 and so on.

Comment: is alexapr an integer column or a string column? Here it is using a string comparison to order them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your alexapr column type to integer.

`ALTER TABLE alexa CHANGE alexapr alexapr` INTEGER IF you're on mysql

Comment: WOWOWWWWWWWWW, its just take a sec to run that query and its change the sequence perfectly. Thanks u yokoloko and Tarang :D

Answer (score 1):

It is treating alexapr column as character type, try to convert the values to number data type.

Comment: Thanks Tarang, it has varchar(20) atm, do I need to change it ti int(11) or so? if yes, then how can i edit it in sql?

Comment: Try to use convert command when you fetch your character column. Once convert is done, then try to order by on it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your 'alexapr' column is a string, instead of an integer and that is why it is sorting in the method as displayed in the question.

Try:
 `CAST(alexapr AS INT)` or `CONVERT(INT, alexapr)`

Update: Since it appears that you are using MySQL, due to the limit clause, the above T-SQL will not work.  Try: `ALTER TABLE alexa CHANGE alexapr alexapr INT;`

Comment: Thanks RobB... but someone already answered before you. nvm.. i am creating a new script and will ask more question in near future. anyways, Thanks for your help :)